# Selecting a node based on the intial context

Tags: php, xpath

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```xml
<r>
  <a>
    <i>
      <k>1</k>
      <d>d1</d>
    </i>
    <i>
      <k>3</k>
      <d>d3</d>
    </i>
  </a>
  <b>
    <i>
      <k>1</k>
      <d>rd1</d>
    </i>
    <i>
      <k>2</k>
      <d>id2</d>
    </i>
    <i>
      <k>3</k>
      <d>rd3</d>
    </i>
  </b>
</r>
```

I select the `i` nodes under `/r/a` and iterate through them to find the associated nodes under `/r/b` and retrieve the value of their `d` nodes as follows:

```
$data = [];
$nodes = $domXPath->evaluate('/r/a/i');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
   $key = $domXPath->evaluate('string(k)', $node);
   $data[] = $domXpath->evaluate("string(/r/b/i[k=$key]/d)", $node);
}
```

This produces the correct result in `$data`:

```
[
  "rd1",
  "rd3",
]
```

My question is whether it is possible to do this without pulling the key out to PHP so something like:

```
$data = [];
$nodes = $domXPath->evaluate('/r/a/i');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
   $data[] = $domXpath->evaluate("string(/r/b/i[k=initial-context()/k]/d)", $node);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a single XPath:

```
$nodes = $domXPath->evaluate('/r/b/i[k = /r/a/i/k]/d');
foreach($nodes as $node) $data[] = $node->textContent;
```

The expression says, for each `/r/b/i` node, allow only if its `k` node matches a corresponding `k` node under `/r/a/i`.